# R delete rows with NA

Tags: r

I deleted rows with NA in column timestamp with

```
data_1<-data_1[!is.na(data_1$timestamp),]
```

and

```
nrow(data_1[is.na(data_1$timestamp),])
```

gives me: 0

But in table viewer there are still 4 rows with NA. Why?
[image]

```
 min(data_1$timestamp)
```

result: "2018-05-07 12:41:09 UTC" 
this is ok, but

```
 max(data_1$timestamp)
```

result is NA

Here are the files:
https://syzygydeutschland-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/florian_roeming_syzygy_de/EdRleruksltMgcvlx18gxSABK15hMZ_swr0GnGMBhXRScw?e=ZJK0UX

Comment: Have you refreshed the view? Providing some data would be helpful here.

Comment: It is possible your column is of class "character" and not a date-time object.  If it is a character class then the Na's are  "NA" and not NA.

Comment: @zack/Dave: yes, i refreshed it and as you can see "max(data_1$timestamp)" is resutling in "NA". Moreover I provided data in Screenshot, do you need more input? The column timestamp has str/class: POSIXct, format: "2018-05-07 22:29:08"

Comment: By 'data' I was referring to a minimal example of what you're experiencing( see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ). It's difficult for me to reproduce the error you're encountering, and thus nearly impossible for me to try and find a solution :(

Comment: The screen shot is of little value.  Please run the function: `dput(head(data_1, 10))`  and paste the output into your question.  The dput function provides the R structure which allows for reproducible testing.

Comment: Here are the files: https://syzygydeutschland-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/florian_roeming_syzygy_de/EdRleruksltMgcvlx18gxSABK15hMZ_swr0GnGMBhXRScw?e=ZJK0UX

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try complete.cases function. It will return the dataframe without any NAs value

```
data_1 <- data_1[complete.cases(data_1),]
```

Comment: It does not work, beacause all rows are recognized as complete data: "nrow(data_1[complete.cases(data_1$timestamp),])" counts the same number as  "nrow(data_1)"